# Should I close the sockets when my application closes?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock

I have 100+ sockets in my server application, should I call `closesocket()` on these 100+ sockets when my application is about to close?

Is it possible for `closesocket()` not to return until the connection is closed for each socket, and hence delay the time it takes for my application to close?

Comment: Try not doing it.  What happens at the clients?

Comment: While on many modern operating systems is not needed, I still do it. Good habits are, well, good to have. :)

Comment: "Should I close the sockets when my application closes?" – **Yes.**

Comment: If 'good habit' means that the app avoidably takes 30 seconds to shut down, it's time to dump the good habit.

Comment: @Martin James When I don't close the sockets on close, the clients will receive `RST` packets.

Comment: @user4592590 - do the clients behave well when they get their RST packets, show a 'server disconnected'  message, try to reconnect or something?  If so, fine..

Comment: @Martin James Yes, I treat an `RST` packet on the client side as a "disconnection packet".

Answer (score 2):

Letting the OS close a socket (or free memory, etc) is a safety feature and should not be solely relied on. It is always a good idea to have a clean exit where your code cleans up after itself.

In C, you would be using close(). See the socket man page for questions on delay: http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

> SO_LINGER
>
> Sets or gets the SO_LINGER option. The argument is a linger
>   structure.

```
struct linger {
     int l_onoff;    /* linger active */
     int l_linger;   /* how many seconds to linger for */ };
```

> When enabled, a close(2) or shutdown(2) will not return until all queued
>   messages for the socket have been successfully sent or the linger
>   timeout has been reached. Otherwise, the call returns immediately and
>   the closing is done in the background. When the socket is closed as
>   part of exit(2), it always lingers in the background.

Comment: 'It is always a good idea to have a clean exit where your code cleans up after itself. ' - no, not really:(

Comment: Posting a Linux man page in response to a Winsocks question is somewhat dangerous. Even if the function signatures happen to be the same, the behavior is often slightly different. As per @Martin's comment: Closing sockets doesn't come for free. Let the system deal with resource management, and make sure to not waste time no server shutdown and restart.

Comment: Ah, I missed the winsock tag. With no specification in the question, I defaulted to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for closesocket not to return immediately and delay the closing of your program. See the SO_LINGER and SO_DONTLINGER and the setsockopt function for more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx